# How to build this query with authentic $row['username']?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've built a page for user permissions and rankings just not to deal with phpmyadmin every time i want to change someones rank or whatever. Now, I have a problem with this query, every time I run all of the users get the same rank.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT $start_from, 20"; 
                $rs_result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error);


                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) { 
                    echo "
                    <tr>
                    <td>".$row['username']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['rank']."</td>
                    <td>
                    <form action='' method='post'>
                    <select name='rank'>
                    <option value='member'>Member</option>
                    <option value='moderator'>Moderator</option>
                    <option value='supermoderator'>Supermoderator</option>
                    <option value='administrator'>Administrator</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='submit' name='change' value='Change' />
                    </form>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    ";

                if (isset($_POST['change'])) {

                    $sql_rank = "UPDATE users SET rank = '".$_POST['rank']."' WHERE username = '".$row['username']."'";
                    $res_rank = mysql_query($sql_rank) or die(mysql_error());

                }
```

Comment: Please, do not `mysql_query` in new applications. It's deprecated, dangerous if used incorrectly like you have here, and will be removed in future versions of PHP. Also, before you write **ANY** more SQL code, read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/) because what you're doing here is extremely hazardous. `$_POST` data should never, ever be put directly in a query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have

```
if (isset($_POST['change'])) {

                    $sql_rank = "UPDATE users SET rank = '".$_POST['rank']."' WHERE username = '".$row['username']."'";
                    $res_rank = mysql_query($sql_rank) or die(mysql_error());

                }
```

inside the while loop. make sure you close the loop and you grab the data with $_POST not $row...

```
if (isset($_POST['change'])) {
      $sql_rank = "UPDATE users SET rank = '".$_POST['rank']."' WHERE username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."'";
       $res_rank = mysql_query($sql_rank) or die(mysql_error());

}
```

Also please consider trying mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you don't transmit the information which user exactly; you only check for `isset($_POST["change"])` which isn't serving any information about which user; it's only indicating that any post request with an `<input name="change"... />` has been submitted.

I suggest to add the value in some hidden input field like `echo '<input type="hidden" name="username" value="'.$row['username'].'" />';`

And then add in your if the condition: `$_POST["username"] == $row['username']`

---

Also you should consider to upgrade to mysqli or PDO.